# SQL Server 2012 drop-down boxes are not working for table names and field names

Tags: sql-server-2012, dropdown

After a recent upgrade from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012, my Management Studio no longer provides the drop-down boxes of table names or of column names.

Prior to the upgrade, when I started typing the table name (ex: after entering `TAP3`) a drop-down box would appear providing a list of all tables that began with `TAP3`. The same applies to the column names.

Now that function no longer works. I have Googled this in general and have checked all of the recommended settings for IntelliSense (not even sure that's what is affecting this!) and haven't found anything to help.

The strange things are that co-workers using the exact same version and tables have no problems with the drop-down boxes. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have found the proper terminology for the function that is not working for me.  It is the "Auto list members" functionality.

Comment: IT finally wiped out my profile and started fresh.  It appears to be working now!  Just thought I'd update this as this was the only solution we found to work!